# Which base class is calling derived overridden method?

Tags: c++, overriding, multiple-inheritance

I have the following code using multiple inheritance. The purpose is to use two interfaces as one in the derived class:

```
struct InterfaceA
{
    virtual void register_stuff();
    virtual void on_state_changed( const State state ) = 0;
};

struct InterfaceB
{
    virtual void register_stuff();
    virtual void on_state_changed( const State state ) = 0;
};

struct Derived : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{
    void register_stuff() override
    {
        InterfaceA::register_stuff();
        InterfaceB::register_stuff();
    }

    void on_state_changed( const State state ) override
    {
        // how can I know who is responding?
    }
};
```

Registering the interfaces will cause an asynchronous call to `on_state_changed`. Is it possible to discern which interface is calling it?

Comment: If you need the information, why not add a parameter telling you what you need?

Comment: Or simply refrain from using multiple inheritance.

Comment: I think this [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/multiple_inheritance.html) has some information on this under the pitfall subheading.

Comment: @BoPersson I cannot modify the Interfaces: those are coming from a lib

Comment: @Ron so is the answer "there is no way to know it"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to add a layer in-between to disambiguate. Here's a small utility that creates those on the fly:

```
template<class Inteface>
struct disambiguate : Interface {
  void on_state_changed( const State state ) override final {
    on_state_changed(state, this);
  }
  virtual void on_state_changed( const State &state, disambiguate* ) = 0;
};
```

And that's it. Then it's a matter of defining your class in terms of this utility:

```
struct Derived : disambiguate<InterfaceA>, disambiguate<InterfaceB>
{
    void register_stuff() override
    {
        InterfaceA::register_stuff();
        InterfaceB::register_stuff();
    }

    void on_state_changed( const State &state, disambiguate<InterfaceA>* ) override
    {
        // Called for A
    }

    void on_state_changed( const State &state, disambiguate<InterfaceB>* ) override
    {
        // Called for B
    }
};
```

I've used another parameter and overloading to make this templatized, but the technique itself can also be done by writing the classes out and calling a virtual function with a new name. The key is to make the original virtual call (via the interface pointer) reach a short thunk that calls the disambiguated function.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively it is possible to provide separate implementations for handlers directly in the code of Derived:

```
    struct Derived : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
     {
        void register_stuff() override
        {
            InterfaceA::register_stuff();
            InterfaceB::register_stuff();
        }

        void InterfaceA::on_state_changed( const State state ) override
        {
            // responding A
        }

        void InterfaceB::on_state_changed( const State state ) override
        {
            // responding B        
        }
  };
```

EDIT: Unfortunately this solution is nonstandard and supported only by Visual C++ compilers.

Comment: This is not compiling for me. Which compiler + version are you using?

Comment: It is VS 2010. It should be classic C++. What error are you getting?

Comment: error: cannot define member function 'InterfaceA::on_state_changed' within 'Derived'
     void InterfaceA::on_state_changed(const State state) override {  }
                          ^

Comment: That is kinda cool. Anybody pushing for it in the C++ commitee?

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about using templates for disambiguating too, but I belive @StoryTeller 's answer is more elegant.

```
struct InterfaceA
{
    virtual void register_stuff();  // calls on_state_changed<InterfaceA>()

    template <typename Interface>
    virtual void on_state_changed( const State state ) = 0;
};

struct InterfaceB
{
    virtual void register_stuff();  // calls on_state_changed<InterfaceB>()

    template <typename Interface>
    virtual void on_state_changed( const State state ) = 0;
};

struct Derived : InterfaceA, InterfaceB
{
    void register_stuff() override
    {
        InterfaceA::register_stuff();
        InterfaceB::register_stuff();
    }

    template <typename Interface>
    void on_state_changed( const State state ) override
    {
        // how can I know who is responding?
        // : "Interface" is responding
    }
};
```